# How to pass JSON from CFFUNCTION

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coldfusion, skype

I am new to JSON, in fact Javascript.  I actually found the code from someone and try to implement this for what I am trying to do.

On my javascript I have:

```
function signin(var1,var2) {
Signin('login.htm?var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2);
}

function skypeme(var1, var2) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "skypeme.cfc",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {a:var1, b:var2},
        success: function(userData) {
            if(userData.LOGIN == 'true' && userData.ID!='') {
                window.location = 'skype:'+userData.ID+'?chat'; 
            }
            else {
                signin(var1,var2);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And on my skypeme.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false"> 
<cffunction name="cfskypeme" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="false"> 
<cfargument name="a" required="true"> 
<cfargument name="b" required="true">  
<cfset var stReturn = structNew()>
<cfset stReturn.LOGIN=false>
<cfset stReturn.ID="">

if user login
    check database for skypeid
        <cfif skypelist.recordcount eq 1>
           <cfset stReturn.LOGIN=true>
           <cfset stReturn.ID=skypelist.skype>
        </cfif>
        <cfreturn SerializeJSON(stReturn)>
if user not login
    <cfreturn SerializeJSON(stReturn)>

</cffunction> 

</cfcomponent>
```

What I want to do is call the cfc and check if user is login, if not call the signin function.  If the user is already signed in, check the database. If skype id is found, kick up skype, if not do nothing.  But what is happening is when I called the skypme() function from my html, nothing happen.  No error but skype doesn't start.

What is the right way of passing the JSON value from cffunction so that it can be executed on the javasctipt side?  I have tried many ways but just can't get it to work.  Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: Nope, your javascript ajax request is expecting json, you should return json to it, not javascript.

Comment: in your skype me.cfc you don't need `cfoutput` or `#` in any of your `cfif` or `cfreturn` statements.

Comment: `<cfif user is login>` is a problem.  There is nothing to suggest those variables actually exist.

Comment: @KevinB How do I change those return to JSON?

Comment: @John that happens for you, just return a struct or an array.

Comment: @MattBusche removing those didn't make any difference

Comment: @DanBracuk the '<cfif user is login>' was just a pseudo code not real CF code.  I think the problem is the passing of parameters back.  I am not sure if 'proxy.data;' the right way to execute?

Comment: @john As per the code, you are not returning any JSON data. You are just passing a string (eg: 'signin(#var1#,#var2#)'). If you want pass json, just create a structure or array and convert it into json by  [SerializeJSON](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_s_03.html). Also please change your question with cf code instead of pseudo code :-p

Comment: @lambypie I have changed it but still not working.  Perhaps it is this code **proxy.data;** that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues: 
your the success portion of your ajax call will always execute if skypeme.cfc returns 200 OK (html header), so returning "false" will actually return the string "false", and success will execute. What you should do is always return a JSON string, and have the format be always the same (also why are you using a query object? use a structure):

```
<cfcomponent output="false"> 
    <cffunction name="cfskypeme" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="false"> 
        <cfargument name="var1" required="true"> 
        <cfargument name="var2" required="true">  
        <cfset var stReturn = structNew()>
        <cfset stReturn.LOGIN=false>
        <cfset stReturn.ID="">

            <cfif user login logic>
                <cfquery name="skypelist"> <!---check db for skypeid--->
                </cfquery>
                <cfif skypelist.recordcount eq 1>
                    <cfset stReturn.LOGIN=true>
                    <cfset stReturn.ID=skypelist.skype>
                </cfif>
            </cfif> <!--- end login logic --->

        <cfreturn SerializeJSON(stReturn)>
    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I have updated it according to your suggestion.  However, I am still not getting any response back from the cfc

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual code. My recommendation would have the cfc return a value no matter what values are passed